# New to Typescript and migrating a Reactjs app to Typescript few unknown errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, frontend, react-tsx

I have a few typescript errors from using TypeStat to help migrate everything over. I have a few unknown errors that I am not sure about how to adjust their types accordingly.

Error #1:

> Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
> Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'Iterable'.
> The types returned by 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'IteratorResult<Element, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult'.
> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props

```
import { Data_Per_Page, Max_Page } from "../data/data";
import Pagination from "react-bootstrap/Pagination";
import PageItem from "react-bootstrap/PageItem";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

interface PagePaginationProps {
  onPageChange: (pageNumber: number) => void;
  nextPage: () => void;
  prevPage: () => void;
  total: number;
}

export default function PagePagination(props: PagePaginationProps) {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [startPageIndex, setStartPageIndex] = useState(1);
  const [endPageIndex, setEndPageIndex] = useState(Max_Page);

  const endIndex = Math.min(Max_Page, Math.ceil(props.total / Data_Per_Page));

  useEffect(() => {
    setEndPageIndex(endIndex);
  }, [props.total]);

  const handlePrevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      if (currentPage === startPageIndex) {
        setStartPageIndex(currentPage - Max_Page);
        setEndPageIndex(currentPage - 1);
      }
      props.prevPage();
      setCurrentPage((curr) => curr - 1);
    }
  };

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage < Math.ceil(props.total / Data_Per_Page)) {
      if (currentPage === endPageIndex) {
        setStartPageIndex(currentPage + 1);
        setEndPageIndex(
          Math.min(
            currentPage + Max_Page,
            Math.ceil(props.total / Data_Per_Page)
          )
        );
      }
      props.nextPage();
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    }
  };

  // @ts-expect-error -- TODO: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  const handlePageClick = (e) => {
    props.onPageChange(e.target.text);
    setCurrentPage(parseInt(e.target.text));
  };

  const RenderItem = () => {
    const item: Element[] = [];
    for (let page = startPageIndex; page <= endPageIndex; page++) {
      item.push(
        // @ts-expect-error -- TODO: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided. Argument of type 'React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
        <PageItem
          key={page}
          onClick={(e) => handlePageClick(e)}
          value={page}
          active={page === currentPage}
          activeLabel=""
        >
          {page}
        </PageItem>
      );
    }
    return item;
  };

  return (
    <Pagination>
      <Pagination.Prev onClick={handlePrevPage} />
      {RenderItem()} // Gives me Error for RenderItem()

      <Pagination.Next onClick={handleNextPage} />
    </Pagination>
  );
}
```

Error #1 is showing for RenderItem()

Error  #2: Solved

Error #3:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.

```
 const getSearchQuery = (zipCodes: any[]) => {
    let query = Default_Search + `sort=breed:${selectedSort.value}&`;
    query += selectedBreeds
      .map((breed) => `dogBreeds=${breed.value}&`)
      .join(""); // gives me an error on .value
    query += zipCodes.map((zipcode) => `zipCodes=${zipcode}&`).join("");
    return query + `ageMin=${minAge.value}&ageMax=${maxAge.value}&`;
  };


useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-expect-error -- TODO: Variable 'cities' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
    const cities = [];
    selectedStates.forEach((state) =>
      cities.push(...getCityByState(state.value).map((city) => city.name))
    ); // gives me same error .value
```

Error #1 I have tried to adjust Element to other types and just get a different or more errors
Error #2 I have tried to remove Dispatch and setStateAction and get more errors that follow down the rest of the line of my types set.
Error #3 I havent done anything with, as I am not sure why its just point to the .value and where that would need to be set.

Comment: The second error is obvious, you haven't defined nor imported `SetStateAction`. Try `React.SetStateAction`, or importing it. For the third error, you don't show what `selectedStates` nor `selectedBreeds` are, so we can't help yet. And for the first error, you don't show what line it's coming from.

Comment: @AndyRay I will try importing setStateAction, what about Dispatch?  selectedStates and selectedBreeds is an array of strings. The first error I made a little comment down by it, but sorry the error is showing for RenderItem()

Comment: @AndyRay just imported Dispatch and setStateAction that helped that error immediately